# Java MVC with Observer-pattern not synchronize for different views

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, observer-pattern, synchronize

I'm writing a simple java Canvas app using Observer-pattern, so I can create multiple synchronous windows(views). But I came into an issue that multiple views synchronize when I debug, but not synchronize when actually running.

Anyone can help me out of this?

Here's how I implemented this (I took @Hovercraft Full Of Eels's advice and trying to creating and posting a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program.):

Listener, which is an interface:

```
public interface CanvasListener {
  void dragMouse(MouseEvent e);
}
```

I have a model, which used to keep notifying all listeners;

```
public class CanvasModel{
  private List<CanvasListener> listeners;
  //...other functions
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    for(CanvasListener listener: listeners){
        listener.dragMouse(e);
    }
  }
}
```

A view implements Listener, and I overrided dragMouse function and implements the canvas:

```
public class CanvasView implements CanvasListener {
  private CanvasModel model;
  private JPanel panel;

  public CanvasView(CanvasModel myModel) {
    // some initializations
    panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        model.mouseDragged(e);
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void dragMouse(MouseEvent e) {
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    g.drawLine(a, b, c, d); //parameters here are not real
    g.dispose();
  }
}
```

And in main class, I created 2 Views.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    CanvasModel model = new CanvasModel();
    new CanvasView(model);
    new CanvasView(model);
}
```

But if I draw on one windows, only one shows the graphics, as shown in [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uv0ilqw0wqx1a1m/Screenshot%202014-12-02%2020.51.27.png?dl=0)

But if I trace into the codes, both windows reflect the graphics, as shown in [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6wv5h0h17b0r5w/Screenshot%202014-12-02%2020.56.44.png?dl=0)

Thanks!

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. And the model should not be calling dragMouse or other listener methods. It should simply be changing its state and then notifying listeners that the state is changed by calling a notification method, that's it.

Comment: Also your view should not draw with a Graphics object obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on a component, but that's the subject of another discussion.

Comment: You're welcome. Understand that the Model should be completely ignorant of the view and the control, meaning it should not know anything about their fields or their methods and should call none. All it knows is that when its state changes, it must notify listeners of the change and that's it. This is absolutely necessary since the Model should be usable by a variety of controls and views.

Comment: You do understand that your question as asked remains un-answerable unless you improve it. Again I suggest your creating and posting an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please check out the link).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks again for you great advice! I tried to creating and posting an mcve and edited my post, please let me know if there's any confusion.

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled nor run by us, so no, it's not a valid mcve.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you what's wrong based on the non-compilable code available, but I can say:

- The CanvasModel holds the key program data, here perhaps it would be a `List<Point>` or maybe even better, a `List<List<Point>>`.* CanvasModel should not be calling a listener method. Data that is shared by all views.
- CanvasModel should most definitely **not** be calling any listener or view methods, such as you have it written.
- Instead, the listeners/Control should be calling CanvasModel methods that can change the state of CanvasModel's variables.
- Then CanvasModel should call notification methods so that any class listening to its state will be notified of changes.
- The listeners can then call methods to extract the state from the model (getter methods).
- And the views would use this information to change their displays.

Comment: Hi @HovercraftFullOfEels, Thank you again for all those great advice about MVC, really makes me understand better about it! I'm trying to improve it and make it more "MVC" :)  Meanwhile, here is my original codes of this program, you can take a look if you want :) https://www.dropbox.com/sh/crt3kinngy66uvi/AABmAksb8lQBl2oP5qH0P56ga?dl=0